# JS не присваивает объект

Tags: javascript

Уже 2 часа сижу с этим багом, хотя он очень банальный.

```
        let aa = this.state.containers.map((obj, idx) => {
            if(obj.mainItem !== null) {
                print('____________________');
                print(newItems[idx]);
                obj.mainItem.content = newItems[idx];
                print(obj.mainItem.content);

            }
            if(obj.mainItem !== null) {
                print(obj.mainItem);

            }
            print('______________________');
            return obj
        });
```

[image]

Он присваивает последний элемент массива newItems, притом, если заменить в дебаге `print(obj.mainItem);` на `print(obj.mainItem.content);` (во втором if) выводит правильно: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если совместить 
   `print(obj.mainItem);
   print(obj.mainItem.content);`
 получаем: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
От выводит правильное значение поля, которое занято , почему-то, другим объектом

Пробовал делать через for in, просто for, ничего не помогает

Comment: Наведите мышку на синюю i и прочитайте предупреждение. Выводите в консоль объекты с помощью JSON.stringify

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо, проблема решилась костылем JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо @AlexeyTen, проблема решилась так:

```
obj.mainItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.mainItem));
obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```